# How do I record text entered in the prompt function of pyautogui?

Tags: python, python-module, pyautogui

I'm writing a program, and I want to make users type feedback in the form of a prompt function in pyautogui. Is there any way I can record the text entered here; preferably in a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Their [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msgbox.html#the-prompt-function) say that `pyautogui.prompt` returns the text input or `None` if users hit cancel. Writing the text input to a file can be done like this:

```
import pyautogui as py

text = py.prompt(text='Do you like apples?', title='Question', default='YES')

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

More easily you can just save the calling of prompt function to a variable,like:

```
import pyautogui
text = pyautogui.prompt(text='Do you like apples?', title='Question', default='YES')
#now you will have the text entered in the prompt saved in 'text' variable
print(text)
```